# Query does not shows a result if there is one row with Sum() function

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a Office Access program to monitor my depts.

I have a table that contains that how much I owe to someone named tbl_depts.

I have another table that contains my payments named tbl_payments.

here is my syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW
    tbl_depts.who,
    tbl_depts.dept,
    Sum(tbl_payments.payment) AS [Paid],
    (tbl_depts.dept - [Paid]) AS remaining
FROM tbl_depts INNER JOIN tbl_payments ON tbl_depts.[ID] = tbl_payments.[dept_ID]
GROUP BY tbl_depts.who;
```

But there is a problem. If there is only one payment for a dept, query showing empty. But this query works perfect if there is two payment for that dept.

What should I do?

Comment: It is an inner join, so I expect it is that you have a typo and there are no rows joining at all.  Can you show the exact test data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using **LEFT JOIN**, when using **INNER JOIN** be sure that **dept_ID** exists on both tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW
    tbl_depts.who,
    tbl_depts.dept,
    Sum(tbl_payments.payment) AS [Paid],
    (tbl_depts.dept - [Paid]) AS remaining
FROM tbl_depts LEFT JOIN tbl_payments 
     ON tbl_depts.[ID] = tbl_payments.[dept_ID]
GROUP BY tbl_depts.who, tbl_depts.dept, (tbl_depts.dept - [Paid]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query above wont even run - the grouping is wrong.
This works:

```
SELECT tbl_depts.ID, tbl_depts.who, tbl_depts.dept, Sum(tbl_payments.payment) AS paid, [dept]-[payment] AS remaining
FROM tbl_payments INNER JOIN tbl_depts ON tbl_payments.dept_ID = tbl_depts.ID
GROUP BY tbl_depts.ID, tbl_depts.who, tbl_depts.dept, [dept]-[payment];
```